# locating a button on outlook Office using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need some help to locate the Create button that comes up after I click on "New Group" in the side menu of office365(the button has a dynamic id)

```
newgrpbutton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title='New group']")
time.sleep(10)
newgrpbutton.click()
time.sleep(15)
actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("tstgrp1")
actions.perform()
time.sleep(20)
#it shows me an error here, Ive tried xpath too but nothing
createbutton=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ms-Button--primary")
time.sleep(8)
actions.double_click(createbutton)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(10)
ntnow=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ms-Button--default")
time.sleep(2)
actions.click_and_hold(ntnow)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and please [edit the question](/posts/56983751/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: it is going to be the same thing for both buttons

Comment: please help....

Comment: it is inside iframe, first switch to frame then try